# Bundling Nokogiri issue

Tags: ruby, bundler, nokogiri

I have an issue where I am able to install Nokogiri with:

```
gem install nokogiri --version
```

But when I run `bundle` I get the following error:

```
ArgumentError: Unmatched double quote: "\\\\'--with-xml2-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.8.0/include/libxml2"
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.8.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.8.5' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I haven’t been able to find anything like this when searching for others with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This [issue](https://github.com/rubygems/bundler/issues/3053) led me to look at my `~/.bundler/config` file which contained the following line:

```
BUNDLE_BUILD__NOKOGIRI: "\\'--with-xml2-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.8.0/include/libxml2"
```

I don’t know why that single quote was there or how it came to be there, but I tried removing it and bundling is now working just fine.